# Spring application URL in scheduled job

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

Is it possible to get the application URL in spring scheduled job (@Scheduled annotated)?
I want to create a job which sends an email with URL to specific page on the application, let's say on `http://localhost:8080/appName/some/specific/url`. The problem is that the part `http://localhost:8080/` will be different in each environment (local,dev,production etc).

Is there any simple way to get a base URL in server-side method which is executed by spring scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do that with a properties file. [This tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/) tells you how you can do it.

The only complex part is you need a way to change the value the properties file is referencing for each of your different environments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to get the base url within your scheduler. You may want to look at work arounds for this, like

1. Use a properties file to store url for each environment
2. Have a Configurartion bean which implements [ServletContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html). This bean would be automatically notified when a web context is initialised.

   public class AppConfig implements ServletContextAware{

   ```
       private String baseUrl;

       public String getBaseUrl(){ 
              return baseUrl; 
       }

       public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext){
           this.baseUrl=servletContext.getRealPath("/");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This one is returning me the real path on disk like /data/home/workspace/tomcat/webapps/..... so I think it is not the thing I'm looking for